# Estrutura de pastas para Backbone sem RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

### O objetivo

Montar uma estrutura de pastas suficiente e inteligente para uma aplicação `Rails 4` + `Backbone`.

### O problema

Como estou no `Rails 4` e eu **ainda** não sei lidar com o `Asset Pipeline` dele + o `RequireJS` (e não há uma gema que faça isso para a versão atual), gostaria de saber uma boa estrutura de pastas para a minha aplicação.

Comment: Veja este projeto https://github.com/dashcoders/djangodash2013/tree/master/django/app/static/js Ele foi desenvolvido em django, porém a estrutura de pastas do Backbone vc pode utilizar a mesma

Comment: @silvio Capitalizar models, collections e etc. em um só arquivo é uma boa prática?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Isso depende to tamanho do seu projeto e da sua necessidade. Neste caso você pode ver que é uma aplicação simples, então não houve necessidade de separar eles. Caso os arquivos sejam maiores e mais complexos, sugiro você separa-los um a um dentro de uma pasta. Por exemplo, uma pasta models e dentro desta os arquivos com seus models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a mesma estrutura de um projeto com requirejs com o asset pipeline do rails. Usar um arquivo só para os models, collections e etc depende muito do tamanho do seu projeto. Exemplo de estrutura:

```
javascripts
├── app
│   ├── collections
│   │   ├── ingredients.js
│   │   ├── recipes.js
│   │   └── users.js
│   ├── mediator.js
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── ingredient.js
│   │   ├── recipe.js
│   │   ├── signup.js
│   │   └── user.js
│   ├── router.js
│   └── views
│       ├── _ingredient.js
│       ├── _recipe.js
│       ├── admin.js
│       ├── base_modal.js
│       ├── signup.js
│       ├── topbar.js
│       ├── user.js
└── vendor
    ├── backbone-0.9.2.js
    ├── backbone.localStorage-min.js
    ├── handlebars.js
    ├── jquery.js
    └── underscore.js
```

No Rails, a diferença é que você vai fazer os require's dos arquivos em um arquivo do sprockets(o application.js por padrão). Lembrando que no Rails o diretório de `javascripts` inicia-se após `app/assets/`.

Comment: O sprockets é o requirejs do Rails então. É isso?

Comment: Isso, você pode gerenciar as dependecias conforme as suas necessidades, entre outras coisas: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#managing-and-bundling-dependencies

Comment: Valeu Thiago! Resolvidasso!